# Get Data from server

Tags: php, android

I managed to save all data to server using this code

```
   HttpClient  httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("www.URL.com");
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
   HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Now i want to get those data in my app .
i have 1 table in the server which has 4 rows
i want to get rows using row id.

Please help me with both server and android code to get saved data from server.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question. StackOverflow is not a free code generator. Please seek assistance elsewhere should you require free source code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a code on the server that pulls the data from the database, and in Android you'll need code to call the function that pulls the data from the database.