# I do not receive information from the server

Tags: php, android

I made a table called city. Where I put city names. I'm going to display them in a recyclerView, but I won't get anything on the run.I do not receive information from the server.Where do you think my problem is?

I checked these pages but did not respond:

[Not Getting data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968302/not-getting-data-from-server)

[Get Data from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185142/get-data-from-server)

my code:

```
public class CitiesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String url= "http://localhost/alibaba/getcity.php";
    ImageView imgBack;
    EditText edtSearch;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<String> cities;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cities);

        setupViews();
        getAllCity();
    }

    private void getAllCity() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                    try {
                      JSONObject jsonObject= response.getJSONObject(i);
                      String city=jsonObject.getString("title");
                      cities.add(city);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new CitiesAdapter(cities));

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
    private void setupViews() {
        cities=new ArrayList<>();
        edtSearch=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_cities_search);
        imgBack=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_cities_back);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv_cities_city);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

my adapter:

```
public class CitiesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CitiesAdapter.citiesvewHolder> {

    private List<String>cities;
    public CitiesAdapter(List<String> cities){
        this.cities=cities;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public citiesvewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.city_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new citiesvewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull citiesvewHolder citiesvewHolder, int i) {
                 String city=cities.get(i);
                   citiesvewHolder.txtTitle.setText(city);
                  citiesvewHolder.parent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
            }
              });
                }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cities.size();
    }

    public class citiesvewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txtTitle;
    RelativeLayout parent;

    public citiesvewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_cityItem_title);
        parent=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rel_cityItem_parent);
    }
}
}
```

my php code:

```
   <?php
    include "connect.php";
    $query="SELECT * FROM city";
    $res=$connect->prepare($query);
    $res->execute();
    $products=array();
    while($row=$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $record=array();
        $record["id"]=$row["id"];
        $record["title"]=$row["city"];

        $products[]=$record;
    }
    echo JSON_encode($products);

    ?>
```

my logcast:

```
10-10 09:57:26.228 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

10-10 09:57:26.245 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

10-10 09:57:26.296 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

10-10 09:57:26.296 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

10-10 09:57:26.299 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

10-10 09:57:26.299 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

10-10 09:57:26.389 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

10-10 09:57:26.423 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

10-10 09:57:26.605 16147-16147/com.example.alibaba E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: Do you see any data in logcat ? It's difficult to identify where is the problem ?

Comment: http://localhost/alibaba/getcity.php recheck this address on postman.

Comment: No adapter attached; skipping layout ,SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length,No adapter attached; skipping layout,Gives these messages in the logcast

Comment: _Hey Reza! It will be much more better if you add logcat in your question_

Comment: I added the logcast to the question